# How is it possible to check inside a method which accepts a String if the string was interpolated in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parameters, arguments, interpolation

How is it possible to check inside a method which accepts a String if the string was interpolated in C#?

I see that the EF is capable of doing this [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql).

```
// String interpolation
var author = db.Authors.FromSql($"SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {id}").FirstOrDefault();
```

> Entity Framework Core will only parameterize interpolated strings if they are supplied inline to the FromSql method call. Interpolated strings declared outside of the FromSql method call will not be parsed for parameter placeholders. In effect, you will be passing a concatenated string directly to the database, which is a SQL injection risk.
>
> The following example is dangerous and should not be used:

```
var sql = $"SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {id}";
var author = db.Authors.FromSql(sql).FirstOrDefault();
```

Before reading the above excerpt I thought that inside a method I am getting a string and it is impossible to get to know how it was constructed. The excerpt made me believe that it is somehow possible.

Comment: The error message is coming from the SQL Client Driver which is getting a command (contains an array of parameters) and; the command text (string query) will have the character '@' indicating there is a parameter.  So the driver can check if there are variables in the command text and then check that each variable has a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interpolated string literal can have a type of `string`, or [`FormattableString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.8), and this is determined by type inference.

EF uses a `FormattableString` as the parameter type for `FromSql`, so that it can get both the format using the `Format` property, and the arguments with the `GetArguments` and `GetArgument` methods.

Here's some code demonstrating the basic usage of this class.

```
var arg1 = 10;
var arg2 = 20;
FormattableString fs = $"Arg1 is {arg1} and Arg2 is {arg2}.";
Console.WriteLine(fs.Format);
Console.WriteLine(fs.GetArgument(0));
Console.WriteLine(fs.GetArgument(1));

// output:
Arg1 is {0} and Arg2 is {1}.
10
20
```

So essentially, `FormttableString` allows EF to prevent SQL injection because it "doesn't format the string immediately", and instead wraps the format string into a nice little object for EF to operate on.